# Buttons are not resizing correctly with responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The buttons on my website are not resizing correctly when moving to smaller screen sizes.

They look okay on a desktop computer. However, I am trying to make the website look nice on mobile as well. I'm not sure what to do when it comes to mobile screens. The first picture is an example of what happens when the screen size is reduced. The second image is the transition that I'm looking for. I'm a beginner at creating websites so any help will be greatly appreciated!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqPOh.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLMAt.jpg)

```css
 #square-wrapper {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#first-square {

  width: 25%;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #e0dbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2.450px;
  margin-right: 2.450px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #23a4de;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px 0px #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block
}

#second-square {

  width: 25%;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #e0dbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2.450px;
  margin-right: 2.450px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #23a4de;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px 0px #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block
}

#third-square {

  width: 25%;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #e0dbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2.450px;
  margin-right: 2.450px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #23a4de;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px 0px #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
  <div id="square-wrapper">


  <div id="first-square">
    <a="" href="/pages/order-lookup">
      <div id="track-order-box" class="half-box"><span>Button 1</span>
        <img src=""></a>


      </div>
  </div>


  <div id="second-square">

    <a="" href="/pages/order-lookup">
      <div id="track-order-box" class="half-box"><span>Button 2</span>
        <img src=""></a>


      </div>
  </div>


  <div id="third-square">

    <a="" href="/pages/order-lookup">
      <div id="track-order-box" class="half-box"><span>Button 3</span>
        <img src=""></a>


      </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello this is the solution, the basic idea is that you need media queries these are triggered when the screen size is below a certain threshold. For more information here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) which explains clearly what you need to do.

```css
 #square-wrapper {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#first-square {

  width: 25%;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #e0dbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2.450px;
  margin-right: 2.450px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #23a4de;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px 0px #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block
}

#second-square {

  width: 25%;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #e0dbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2.450px;
  margin-right: 2.450px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #23a4de;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px 0px #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block
}

#third-square {

  width: 25%;
  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #e0dbdb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 2.450px;
  margin-right: 2.450px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #23a4de;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px 0px #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 
 #first-square {
   width: 100%;
 }
 
 #third-square{
  width:48%;
  margin:0 0 0 1%;
  padding:0;
 }
 
 #second-square{
  width:48%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  padding:0;
 }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 
#first-square {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px 30% 0 30%;
}
 
#third-square{
  width:30%;
  margin: 10px 30% 0 30%;
}
 
#second-square{
 width:30%;
 margin: 10px 30% 0 30%;
   }
  }
```

```html
  <div id="square-wrapper">


  <div id="first-square">
    <a="" href="/pages/order-lookup">
      <div id="track-order-box" class="half-box"><span>Button 1</span>
        <img src=""></a>


      </div>
  </div>


  <div id="second-square">

    <a="" href="/pages/order-lookup">
      <div id="track-order-box" class="half-box"><span>Button 2</span>
        <img src=""></a>


      </div>
  </div>


  <div id="third-square">

    <a="" href="/pages/order-lookup">
      <div id="track-order-box" class="half-box"><span>Button 3</span>
        <img src=""></a>


      </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question and for the link with more information on media queries. It work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack, a lot of basic syntax errors that are tripping you up.
For instance: `<a=""` is not correct html.

You also have a overlapping tags like so:

```
<div> <a> </div> </a>
```

This is not correct html either.

You can have:

```
<div> <a> </a> </div>
```

or:

```
<a> <div> </div> </a>
```

The reason your question got a downvote is because people are quite mean on stack overflow, any question that doesn't have a difinitive answer usually gets shot down quickly. If you're a beginner, knowing what kinds of questions to ask can be really hard without knowing the basics.

I'd really recommend following an online course in html, css and javascript. The basics. One day it'll just click and you'll find you can learn things really quickly. Even professional coders, spend half their time copying and pasting things they found on google, so knowing how to ask a question is actually a big part of it. Hope that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips.  I do really appreciate it. I will keep this in mind moving forward.